# Menu item issue in html, jquery asp.net

Tags: jquery, html

I need help to implement a complete senario.

i want to save MenuItems in a table(specify me table structure) in database and then load Menu from that table(i want to do dynamic menu and menu item).To create menu in html i am using `<ul>` and `<li>`.

Now i will allow administrator to assign pages to any role(these pages and folders ll be saved in above table).

Now i want to load these pages etc and role power to Dictionary OR session OR anything which suit this senario.and when any user/role can click on anypage link,i want to check at that time that, IS this user have right to view/edit etc this page?

How i ll implement all these?i am using jquery ajax and asp.net.

A quick response ll be apreciated.

Comment: i have roles and users saved.i assigned roles to users.i have created menu statically from <lu></lu> html.i want to dynamic this.and want admin to assign pages to roles like admin can view/add etc all pages while role user can only check companylist.aspx but not addcompany.aspx(these pages r child of company menu).i need table to save this setting and then want to check.....